# MySQL REGEXP not matching strings

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm doing a MySQL query where I need to match two strings within a long string but can't get it to work. This is what I've tried.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (mycol REGEXP '/~20\|2~/' AND mycol REGEXP '/~14\|1~/')
```

Here is what the string looks like

```
~20|2~14|1~15|1~16|1~1|1397|1|0:0:0:0||~17|1~18|1~
```

I want to select all rows that contain both of these substrings

```
~20|2~ AND ~14|1~
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify either you want to have both in one row or just if one is enough to select the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out please, thsi is only selecting the rows that has both your strings.

- ### Edit:

**The reason here that your original regex didn't work:**

[`Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent the newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in your REGEXP strings.`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html)

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f933f/9)

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM vendor 
WHERE (vname REGEXP '~20\\|2~' 
AND vname REGEXP '~14\\|1~')
;
```

---

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f933f/2)

Query: Notice that I have used a different table/sample data than yours. But copied your data row and changed a bit to trigger the correct `regex`.

Sample Data:

```
| VID |                                              VNAME |
------------------------------------------------------------
|   1 | ~20|2~14|1~15|1~16|1~1|1397|1|0:0:0:0||~17|1~18|1~ |
|   2 |               ~20|2~14|1397|1|0:0:0:0||~17|1~18|1~ |
|   3 | ~20|2~14|1~15|1~16|1~1|1397|1|0:0:0:0||~17|1~18|1~ |
|   4 |       ~20|2~1|1~16|1~1|1397|1|0:0:0:0||~17|1~18|1~ |
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM vendor 
WHERE (vname REGEXP '~20\[|]2~' 
AND vname REGEXP '~14\[|]1~')
;
```

Results:

```
| VID |                                              VNAME |
------------------------------------------------------------
|   1 | ~20|2~14|1~15|1~16|1~1|1397|1|0:0:0:0||~17|1~18|1~ |
|   3 | ~20|2~14|1~15|1~16|1~1|1397|1|0:0:0:0||~17|1~18|1~ |
```

Comment: @PaulMG is this what you wanted to get? Please comment. You only need to specify the square bracket around `[|]` as it was working as an `OR` in the `regex` before. Now you treat is as a character to be found.

Comment: Hi @bonCodigo that works in my code thanks. It seems odd to use the backslash before the square bracket so I tried without and that works too. If anything I thought the backslash should be before the pipe like so [\|]. I tried that and it also works... weird

Comment: @PaulMrG the most important thing here is that you need to wrap the `|` for `regex` to not mistake is as the operator.. So yours would have worked wiht your current answe as long as you had doubled the `escape syntax the backslash \`. Check here [sqlfiddle]( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47e3c/11) This is more accurate. So I am glad you expriemented and got it worked. Please mark as answer then :) so the community knows that you problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (mycol REGEXP '~20\|2~' AND mycol REGEXP '~14\|1~')`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51340/2)

Comment: Yes, but it selects other rows that don't have both substrings, see edit of your fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bb8d/1